# Change column names dynamically

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table which is having multiple column names shown in below (Old Column Name).
Now I need to change those column names into Required column names as shown below)
Ex: ('xyz','ID') shoul change as ID.value (i.e find **'xyz',**  and Get 2nd string first and replace 'xyz', into 'value' followed by "."  final name will be like **ID.value**)
Similarly for abc - value1

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Select second tuples to `Series` and add counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
s = df.columns.str[1].to_series() 

df.columns = s + '.Value' + s.groupby(s).cumcount().astype(str).replace('0','')
```

Or use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
c = df.columns.str[1]
df.columns = c + '.Value' + pd.Series(pd.factorize(c)[0]).astype(str).replace('0','')
```